# Cannot access offset of type string on string codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem with json_encode from foreach, I want to get field data. This is my sample code:

```
foreach ($report_last_6_days as $day => $report):
            $mapping_reports[$day]['date'] = $day;
            foreach ($report as $key => $value):
                $obj_data = json_decode($value['data'],true);
                foreach ($obj_data as $key_obj => $r):
                    $key_array_commodity                                    = array_search($r['id'], array_column($commodities, 'id'));
                    $satuan                                                 = $commodities[$key_array_commodity]['satuan'];
                    $price                                                  = $r['value'] ? (int) $r['value'] : '-';
                    $mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['id']          = $r['id'];
                    $mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['name']        = $r['nama'];
                    $mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['satuan']      = $satuan;
                    $mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['prices'][]    = $price;
                    $mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['geomean']     = geomean($mapping_reports[$day]['data'][$r['id']]['prices']);
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
```

Comment: Error messages apply to one line of code, that line is mentioned in the error message. Please always provide ALL the error message, not just a summary

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.

Comment: Well then `$value['data']` is not what you think it is